# Logout from a page such that pressing the back button of browser doesn't show a protected page

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am using codeigniter-3.0.4. i load the displaySorted function inside login_controller when a user provides a valid email-id and password. The check_database method does that for me and there i set my own $sess_array as shown in the code below. This is my login_controller.

```
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model('user_model','',TRUE);


}
public function index()
{
    //$this->load->model('user_model');
    $this->load->view('login_view');
}
```

My login and check_database function inside this controller

```
function login()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('login_email', 'Email');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','callback_check_database');//calling the check_database function

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
        $this->load->view('login_view');

    }
    else
    {
        //$this->displayDatabase();
        //$this->load->view('adminPanel_view') ;
        //echo true;exit;
        redirect('login_controller/displaySorted');

    }
}
function check_database()
 {

    //Field validation succeeded. Now Validating against database
    $email = $this->input->post('login_email');
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    //echo "$email $password"; exit;

    //query the database
    $result = $this->user_model->login($email, $password);

    if($result)
    {
        $sess_array = array();
        foreach($result as $row)
        {
            $sess_array = array(
                'id' => $row->ID,
                'login_email' => $row->email,
                'logged_in' => 1
            );

            $this->session->set_userdata($sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid Email or password');
        return false;
    }
}
```

i am using this inside my displaySorted function:

```
function displaySorted($sortBy = 'DeviceName',$sortOrder = 'asc',$offset=0)
{
    $dataS = $this->session->userdata();      

    if(isset($dataS))
     {
        //somecode here
      }
    else
    {
       //redirect to login here
     }
```

and finally my logout function

```
  function logOut(){
    //echo 'Logout';exit;
    //$this->session->set_userdata('logged_in',FALSE);
    $this->session->unset_userdata($sess_array);
    //$this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login_controller/login', 'refresh');
}
```

i am unable to destroy the $sess_array with this method. i have used some other things too but when i ever i press the back button inside the browser i can see my displaySorted functionality which should not be visible to me. i have read in the codeigniter documentation that i cannot pass an associative array in unset_userdata() method. what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

set your session in `check_database` function try like this

```
 $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
```

then in `logout` function to unset session try to

```
$this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
```

in `__construct()`function use this to prevent login on click back button

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {
        redirect('auth/login', 'refresh');//where are you want to redirect controller function 
    }

    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");

}
```

Comment: still pressing the back arrow key takes me to the protected displaySorted funciton

Comment: in construct function use this to login   `if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == FALSE) {
            redirect('controller_name/function_name', 'refresh');
        }`

Comment: i have added this but now my browser keeps on refreshing the page in an infinite loop and then the browser gives me an error.

Comment: am updated my answer please check construct function

Comment: i am sorry but it makes no difference.

Comment: actually am using two controller one controller is use to view login form and another controller used for login check and create session and destroy session. is your  all function in same controller

Comment: yes they are all in the same controller. How have you set up the controllers?? can you please elaborate? and thank you for your prompt answers

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107207/discussion-between-rakib-roni-and-umair-ashfr).